# how to define a structure in a class?

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, structure

I have a class:

```
class systemcall
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int pid;
        int fptrCntr;
        OpenFile openfileptrs[10];

    }processTable[100];

    public:
         //other stuff...
}
```

I have a member function

```
/* this function initializes the process table. */
void systemcall::initpTable()
{
    int i = 0;

    for ( i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
     processTable[i].fptrCntr = 0;
    }

}
```

The line `processTable[i].fptrCntr = 0;` gives an error:

```
systemcall.cc:86: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
```

i have almost pulled all my hair out!!! Any ideas why this is happening? I even put the structure in the systemcall.cc file, but no use.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the `typedef` before the declaration of `processTable` since you are declaring an object, not a type.  After defining `processTable` as a type, you then proceed to use it as a member object, which confuses the compiler.

Comment: After removing typedef this is what happens: In another file (exception.cc) where i have  systemcall *mysyscall = new systemcall; i get this error:  exception.cc:57: error: no matching function for call to `systemcall::systemcall()

Comment: @rashid: Is `OpenFile` default constructible?  You will need that to easily initialize the array member of `systemcall`.

Comment: after commenting out OpenFile it complied like a charm. Well OpenFile has a constructor, but how would i check if it is default constructible? I am new to these terminologies. Thank you

Comment: @rashid: Default constructible just means a constructor that takes no arguments as in `OpenFile() : /*initializer stuff*/ {}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class systemcall
{
    struct ProcessTable
    {
        int pid;
        int fptrCntr;
        OpenFile openfileptrs[10];

    };

    ProcessTable processTable[100];

    public:
         //other stuff...
};
```